# ArcGIS Network Analyst updating data

Tags: arcgis-server, network-analyst

We have a ArcGIS Network Analyst service which uses enterprise geodatabase (Oracle).

Frequently we receive updated data in shp format and we want to;

- Overwrite existing data which we keep in database. (Delete old rows, update existing rows and add non-existing rows)
- Reload - build network analyst service with minimum down time.

The method we use is really painful. We delete dataset, import data create network dataset.

Comment: I don't think there's any easier method to do that. You should just try to automate the process (either with ModelBuilder or Python), if you need to reuse it frequently. This would also allow you to run the process at scheduled hours (e.g. at night), so that the service is down when it's less used.